# Error when running 'embark run'

Tags: ethereum

When run the command 'embark run'. I got the error message:

```
Running "deploy_contracts:development" (deploy_contracts) task
Warning: ==== can't connect to localhost:8101 check if an ethereum node is running Use --force to continue.
Error: ==== can't connect to localhost:8101 check if an ethereum node is running
```

Could you please give me some help about it?

Comment: Do you already know the new [Ethereum Stack Exchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embark)?

Answer (score 1):

[Before you can run embark](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework/blob/develop/README.md#usage---demo), you have to **run an ethereum rpc simulator**, simply run:

```
$ embark simulator
```

Or Alternatively, you can run a REAL ethereum node for development purposes:

```
$ embark blockchain
```

By default embark blockchain will mine a minimum amount of ether and will only mine when new transactions come in. This is quite usefull to keep a low CPU. The option can be configured at config/blockchain.yml

You will see a geth node starting in the terminal. Then, open another terminal and type:

```
$ embark run
```

This will automatically deploy the contracts, update their JS bindings and deploy your DApp to a local server at http://localhost:8000

Note that if you update your code it will automatically be re-deployed, contracts included. There is no need to restart embark, refreshing the page on the browser will do.

See also [newest embark tagged questions on Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embark) for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

In your embark project directory:

run `$ embark blockchain` and leave this running on your terminal.

Open a new terminal, `cd <yourProject>` and run `$ embark run`

You will now be up and running on your local host at `http://localhost:8000`